# x86 assembly - masm32: absolute breakdown of multiplication and division

Tags: assembly, x86, divide

I have looked all over the internet for a simple-to-understand evaluation of how to multiply and divide in masm32 assembly. My questions are:

1. Where should I place the numbers being multiplied?
2. Where should I place the numbers being divided?
3. Where does the remainder go in the division?

Could someone please answer this for me?

Thanks,

Progrmr

Comment: RTFM.  Get the Intel processor manuals, volumes 2a and 2b and review the MUL and DIV instructions.  http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Comment: ... or in [this online book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic)

Comment: Looking at this and other questions, I wonder if there is a reason you are learning x86 asm?  It is the LAST asm you want to learn, if this is for a class I understand, if not learn a different asm first, I have a number of suggestions.  If you must learn asm first, learn 8088/8086 using a simulator, dont try anything newer until you have a solid foundation for the original.

Comment: The intel manual is great. I have downloaded the entire three-part manual. It is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question can be very easily found by looking at the proper page of the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Instruction Set Reference](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf). In this case, you're looking for the `MUL` and `DIV` instructions (in case you're operating on unsigned operands) or `IMUL` and `IDIV` instructions, which are used for signed integer multiplication and division.

So, in case you really don't feel like looking through the manual :

1. One of the operands of the multiplication must be placed in the `EAX` register if you're using `MUL`. This is a bit more flexible if you're using the `IMUL` instruction, which allows you to specify the source and destination registers.
2. The number being divided is always a 64-bit number in 32-bit mode. The high bits go into `EDX`, while the lower bits go into `EAX`.
3. The remainder is always placed in `EDX`.

Comment: How does one know what size their number is (32-64 bit, 8-bit, etc)?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Basically, it depends on the form of the instruction that you're using and the mode the processor is running in.

Comment: When using a programming language like C for example how do you know the size of the variable?  You know from the definition of the variable.  In assembly the size of the register is defined in the intel manuals.  the same manual with the answers to this and other questions you have.

Comment: `IMUL` also does unsigned multiplication, because signedness only affects the high half of the result, which it (well, the forms with more than one operand) doesn't generate anyway.

Comment: How can you specify the source and destination registers?