# x86 assembly Which registers are involved in multiplication and division

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

Here is my code:

```
.data
        ans1 db 0
        ans2 db 0
.data? 
        in1 db 100 dup(?) ; first input value
        in2 db 100 dup(?) ; second input value
.code
start:
        ; here I have code for input 
        ; I get 2 nums, and I want to multiply and divide them
        ; here is what I already have to mul/div them:
        lea eax, in1
        lea edx, in2
        imul eax ; multiply in1 and in2
        mov ans1, eax ; move result to ans1
        xor eax, eax ; clear register
        xor edx, edx ; " "
        lea eax, in1
        lea edx, in2
        idiv eax ; divide in1 by in2
        mov ans2, eax ; move result to ans2
        lea eax, ans1
        push eax
        call StdOut ; print ans1 (I have include instructions at the start)
        lea ebx, ans2
        push ebx  
        call StdOut ; print ans2 ("")
```

My question: 
1. Exactly which register do I put `in1` and `in2` to multiply them?
2. " " to divide them?
3. Where is the remainder stored in a division?

And don't worry about a general statement, could you just tell me which registers will definitely (as close as possible) work in multiplication and division.

NOTE:
Some may say that this post is a repetition of [x86 assembly - masm32: absolute breakdown of multiplication and division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684736/x86-assembly-masm32-absolute-breakdown-of-multiplication-and-division) , but (correct me if I am wrong) it is more respectful of the forum community to make a new post, rather than add comments to the old one and make it off topic.

Comment: The correct answer to this would be the same as the answer to the linked question, [RTFM](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing assembly, you should never be too far away from [the reference spec](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf):

```
Unsigned multiply (AX ← AL ∗ r/m8).
```

Tells you everything you need to know. The result will be placed in `AX`. The sources are AL and any 8 bit register or memory location.

EDIT

Your question isn't/wasn't formatted correctly, your questions were on the same line.

Division is `DIV`:

```
Unsigned divide AX by r/m8, with result stored in AL ← Quotient, AH ← Remainder
```

Seriously: read the manual.

Comment: @Progrmr It's all in the documentation. If you're familiar with x86, the excerpts I posted are all you need. If you're not, you need to do some research, reading, and learning before posting on SO.

Comment: The issue is that the program keeps shutting down as a result of the multiplication and division. I have done research, and testing, I have read the manual's section on `mul` and `div`, I wouldn't be posting on SO if I could do it, and if I hadn't done reading, research and testing.

Comment: @Progrmr: Start using a debugger too. Why do we have to debug your stuff for you? Learn the tools.

Comment: 8-bit operand size is a special case, and the question is about `imul eax` which squares EAX into EDX:EAX, and `idiv eax` which is ... almost always useless.